# Regex Pattern to match Ticket IDs in Javascript (Prefix-Dash-Digits)

Tags: javascript, regex, jira, redmine

I am trying to get a Ticket IDs in a log message to be wrapped with a link to the appropiate URL in Javascript. I am still relatively a newbie when it comes to regex.

```
Input:

MYPROJECT-123 My Commit

Output:

(MYPROJECT-123)[http://url/MYPROJECT-123] My Commit
```

I am scratching my head in figuring out why my regex pattern will not work. Any clues?

```
var logMessage = "MYPROJECT-123 My Commit";
var projectId = "MYPROJECT";

var ticketPattern = new RegExp('/^('+projectId+'-*\d)$', 'g');

var mdLogMessage = logMessage.replace(ticketPattern, "($1)[http://url/$1]");

console.log(mdLogMessage);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `,` after `"` in your code? You failed to paste?

Comment: My bad, it was a paste fail. Fixed syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your regexp as below. But I don't know javascript regexp mechanism. I believe someone explain it.

before:

```
var ticketPattern = new RegExp('/^('+projectId+'-*\d)$', 'g');
```

after:

```
var ticketPattern = new RegExp('^('+projectId+'-*\\d*)');
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me

what worked better for me to get all instances was when I removed the '^' character like so

var ticketPattern = new RegExp('('+projectId+'-*\\d*)', "g");

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
var ticketPattern = new RegExp('/'+projectId+'(?=-\d*\s*My Commit)', 'g')
```

so the regex pattern will be for example:

```
MYPROJECT(?=-\d*\s*My Commit)
```

see demo with 'MYPROJECT' as the projectId here: http://regex101.com/r/lM7rJ3

Comment: sorry, that didn't work for me because I needed the regex to take any message instead of a hardcoded "My Commit"